# Images not showing up on WordPress custom theme

Tags: wordpress, image

I have a custom WordPress theme installed and my images are referenced as such:

index.php:

```
<img src="images/newlogo.png" height="110px" width="400px"/>
```

My `images` folder is relative to my `index.php` from which I have included the above code.

My images are not showing when I render the webpage in a browser, it is showing the default image not found thumb instead.

Image filepath:

```
wp-content/themes/my-theme/images/newlogo.png
```

Homepage (index.php) filepath:

```
wp-content/themes/my-theme/index.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `index.php` is a template that will be loaded by WordPress's main entry point (at /index.php) and the code behind it; as such its URL won't be `...wp-content/themes/my-theme/index.php`. You should use the WordPress method [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) to find your theme's directory from any of your theme template files.

For example:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/images/newlogo.png" height="110px" width="400px"/>
```

Basically, any relative paths to images from a web page are considered as relative to that web page's URL. However, with WordPress templates, you can't know for sure what the actual URL will be -- your `index.php` template might (probably *will*) be used for many different pages on your site, at many different URLs. It could be used at the top level for a page at `/about`, and also for an entry at `/blog/2014/01/05/typical-blog-post`, for example.

WordPress handles both building the URLs and loading your template file into them appropriately. But this means that you can't depend on the URL of the template you're writing being a constant. Instead, WordPress provides a series of functions, like `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`, to let you grab and output the correct URI to your stylesheet files as necessary.

Comment: Great explanation on file paths in WordPress... This works fine. Thanks

Comment: what when images path declare in css file?

Comment: @bhautikmewada191 In a CSS file, you can use a relative path from the CSS file to the image. For example: in your theme directory, you have both your `style.css` and an `images` directory containing `whatever.jpg`, then you can use `url(images/whatever.jpg)` in your CSS.